# How can I perform an animate and a fade out at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want "app1" to move to the left and fade out at the same time?

The functions are performing them one by one. I want it to happen at the same time. I dont want it to move left and then fade out.

THANKS!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Forget Me Not</title>

<style>

body
{
background-color:#66d9ff;
}

#app1{
position:absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
z-index:0;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
background:white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
text-align:center
}

img.appIMG1{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

img.appIMG2{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".appIMG1").click(function () {
        $("#app1").animate({
            left: '250px'
        });
    $("#app1").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- php stuff goes the body -->
<div id="app1"><p><b><u><font face="TimeBurner" color="#66d9ff" size="6">Do you want to make a reminder?</b></u></font></p>
<br>
<img class="appIMG1" border="0" src="YES.png" align="left" hspace=1.8% >
<img class="appIMG2" border="0" src="NO.png" align="right" hspace=2%>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest fix for your code is to add `queue:false` to your animate:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".appIMG1").click(function () {
        $("#app1").animate({
            left: '250px'
        },{queue:false}); // <-- here
    $("#app1").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HFLur/

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the opacity with the same `.animate` call

```
$("#app1").animate({
    left: "250px",
    opacity: 0
});
```

Comment: A zero opacity doesn't remove it from the DOM flow like `fadeOut()` does, as it sets `display:none`

Comment: Although, it has `position:absolute;` so I suppose in this case it wouldn't matter :)

Comment: I'm a bit of noob... I would like to know bit a more of what you meant about the DOM flow, and why position:absolute wouldn't make it matter?

Comment: @Ebadly what he's saying is that if it were not `position: absolute` there could still be a big vertical block of space taken up by the div since it's still there, just transparent.  Since it is `position: absolute` it doesn't interrupt the flow of other elements anyway

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/vMsgf/)***

Just animate its opacity at the same time

```
$("#app1").animate({
     left: '250px',
     opacity: 0.0
});
```